# Drupal 7 : Access Denied upon order completion And user logout?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

in drupal commerce every time logged in as a authenticated user and can get all the way through checkout until I am redirected back to the site.

redirected to this page:

/checkout/15/payment/return/GSudAHSfaC6km6N5qbLb8jNB8Wu3x3DZ0TzvWT0O4io?payment_method=paypal&token=EC-5Y966101448403611&PayerID=HF6BGTV3LGDT4

I get sometimes an Access Denied error and user log out ! and The order is not processed. And sometimes is ok and processed complete !

I can't see that I am missing any permissions that would prevent anything. I also can't see where I would specify the page to return the user to at this point in the process. Any thoughts?

This problem only on chrome ! firefox is ok !!

Comment: Same Problem Bro !

Comment: I have same problem, too. I think, this is a chrome bug. After checkout, I get sms code correctly. But then chrome is closing user session and my order is failed.

Comment: I believe that URL is the redirect from PayPal. Does the order process on PayPal's end? Is there anything in the Database Log module?